# Batch file - Custom CMD commands; /? or help display?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I know that when you type a command then pass a question mark, it will return information on the syntax, such as `set /?`. So how can I do this in a batch file? Such as if I have my batch file in the cmd's root directory and I call it such as "batchTest /?" that it will display a help message?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
IF "%1"=="/?" (
    ECHO help line 1
    ECHO help line 2
    ECHO help line 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an if statement to check for a paramater of '/?' and print out the help information if it is found.  Here is an example:

```
if '%1'=='/?' goto :HELP

echo Here is the Main batch file

goto :EOF

:HELP
echo Print Help Information
```

Comment: I think `/I `is not necessary here as long as you're only checking for `/?` cuz neither `/` nor `?` has uper or lower case.

Comment: Yep, you are correct.  I pulled this out of another batch file that did need it.  Thanks.  I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
rem This is the custom command you are writing
set sh=netsh
rem coding structure
echo This is my own syntax

set /p input= EOF>

if %input%==sh goto sh

:sh
%sh%
rem I think this should work too!
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 